# Cannot get Camel failover to connect to brokers

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am a novice with Camel, but have successfully created routes, etc. The problem I am having is with the failover:() feature. I can connect to either of our brokers individually, but when I try to use failover with both, neither host will accept a connection.

Also just realized this could be more of an ActiveMQ issue and not Camel.

I've tried these URLs (redacted):

```
failover:(amqps://message_broker_1:5671,amqps://message_broker_2:5671)?nested.randomize=false&nested.initialReconnectDelay=100&transport.trustStoreLocation=/path/to/truststore.jks&transport.trustStorePassword=(redacted)&transport.keyStoreLocation=/path/to/client-cert.jks&transport.keyStorePassword=(redacted)&transport.verifyHost=false
failover:(amqps://message_broker_1:5671,amqps://message_broker_2:5671)?maxReconnectAttempts=5&transport.startupMaxReconnectAttempts=3&maxReconnectDelay=2000&randomize=false&initialReconnectDelay=1000&transport.trustStoreLocation=/path/to/truststore.jks&transport.trustStorePassword=redacted)&transport.keyStoreLocation=/path/to/client-cert.jks&transport.keyStorePassword=(redacted)&transport.verifyHost=false
```

EDIT
I moved the SSL creds out of the URI and created an SslContext object and called setSswlContext() in the JmsConnectionFactory. Still does not work. The problem appears to be in the failover connection factory.

I get the following series of messages for both:

```
Aug 23 06:33:18 [FailoverProvider: connect thread] DEBUG o.a.q.jms.provider.failover.FailoverProvider - Connection attempt:[1] to: amqps://message_broker_1:5671 in-progress
Aug 23 06:33:21 [FailoverProvider: connect thread] INFO  o.a.q.jms.provider.failover.FailoverProvider - Connection attempt:[1] to: amqps://message_broker_1:5671 failed
Aug 23 06:33:21 [FailoverProvider: connect thread] DEBUG o.a.q.jms.provider.failover.FailoverProvider - Connection attempt:[1] to: amqps://message_broker_2:5671 in-progress
Aug 23 06:33:21 [FailoverProvider: connect thread] INFO  o.a.q.jms.provider.failover.FailoverProvider - Connection attempt:[1] to: amqps://message_broker_2:5671 failed
```

Those repeat forever.

When I use this, I connect with no problems:

```
amqps://message_broker_1:5671?transport.trustStoreLocation=/path/to/truststore.jks&transport.trustStorePassword=(redacted)&transport.keyStoreLocation=/path/to/client-cert.jks&transport.keyStorePassword=(redacted)&transport.verifyHost=false
```

I've searched quite a bit, had colleagues look at it, our admins - nobody can spot the problem. I've tried a lot of variations, I always get the same failure messages.

Is there something wrong with the syntax, what I have missed?

Thanks

Comment: I never discovered why this failover was not working, but the "solution" was to use openwire instead.